# Page Headers in ReportViewer Report Displaying A Variable

Tags: reportviewer, reporting-services

I am trying to add the variable SName to the report header. I copied this =First(ReportItems!SName.Value) after reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252093%28VS.80%29.aspx  and it works on the First page of the report.
However, on the second through penultimate page it becomes blank (i think because the textbox Sname doesnt appear on the page anymore) and then on the last page it displays Blank.

I need the value from the textbox SName to appear on every page of the report.
Any ideas are much appreciated.
Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 0):

OK I had to make a textbox which I set hidden=true and held the value so that the information would be present on each page, yet not visible to the user, ugly but it works. =ReportItems!SName.Value where SName is the name of a textbox which is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Select the TextBox Properties, in the General Tab check "Repeat report item ..." option and then select Data Region. It Works!!!